# What date format is this? How do I convert it to a human readable date format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I am returning some dates directly (unmodified) from the a database query to the front-end:

`1540906457020`

`1540920856937`

`1540920856970`

What is this dateformat called and how do I convert it to a human readable date, such as "03/21/2019" (or some variant with timestamp appended)?

Comment: `new Date(1540906457020)`?

Comment: `new Date(1540920856937)` will give you a JavaScript Date object, then you have many ways to format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's based on the [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), but it's counting milliseconds rather than seconds. ([ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) calls this the "Time Value".) The [Date object in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) uses this value underneath the surface. If you use the integer value as a parameter in the Date constructor, you'll get a Date object which should be handled quite well by most browsers.

```
const happyDateObject = new Date(1540920856937);
```

If you want a bit more control over what's going on, or want some more utilities that help you customize what the date looks like and how to manipulate it, I'd recommend [the moment.js librar](https://momentjs.com/)y. It's widely used because it's so useful. Since it's really just a wrapper for the standard Javascript Date object, moment objects convert quite easily to Date objects (when you need to do so). You'd construct the value in a similar way:

```
const happyMoment = moment(1540920856937)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Unix timestamp (since Jan 01 1970), in milliseconds

You can convert it using e.g. this link here: https://www.epochconverter.com/

There are plenty of topics on how to convert timestamps to strings.

Start by using

```
new Date(1540920856937)
```

Comment: Specifically, it's a _Unix_ timestamp (since Jan 01 1970), in milliseconds.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe—it's just a number that can be used as an [*ECMAScript time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range)). Mentioning UNIX is just a red herring, they both happen to use the same epoch (as do many programming languages and systems).